# Autocorrelation function in R for observational data

Tags: r, time-series, autocorrelation

I'm trying to replicate an analysis done in Stata with R that involves calculating the autocorrelation for a particular outcome measured in many different areas. I've already run a linear regression on the data, which produced residuals for the outcome of interest. While I can't post my actual data, here is what it sort of looks like:

```
year<-c('2003', '2004', '2005','2003', '2004', '2005','2003', '2004', '2005')
location<-c(rep('North', 3), rep('South',3), rep('West',3))
resid <-c(-2.42, -3.563, -2.112, -0.543, 2.391, -1.556, -0.177, 0.983, 1.225)
mydata<-data.frame(location,year, resid)
mydata

  location year resid
1    North 2003  -2.420
2    North 2004  -3.563
3    North 2005  -2.112
4    South 2003  -0.543
5    South 2004   2.391
6    South 2005  -1.556
7     West 2003  -0.177
8     West 2004   0.983
9     West 2005   1.225
```

I'm interested in the autocorrelation in the residuals, so I'm running the following:

```
 myacf <-acf(mydata$resid, plot=F)
```

I'm not getting the same autocorrelation values as I got with Stata. I'm wondering if I should be specifying somehow that my data aren't a continuous time series from t=1 to t=9, but rather 3 sets of 3 time points that were measured in different locations (so really there can only be lag of 1 or 2, at least in the toy data above).

Also, above, I've made it so every region has 3 years of outcomes, but in my real (more complicated) dataset, some regions might have more rows than others (e.g., North might have 7 rows for 2000-2006, but South might only have 5 because we missed the outcome in 2003 and 2006 so there are no residuals for those 2 years, etc.). Any help would be appreciated in understanding whether acf() is the right way to approach this problem or not, and if so, what I might consider changing.

Comment: I believe acf() is set up for univariate time series.  You might need to work with the gls() function in the nlme package, which allows you to model temporal and spatial correlation with a variety of functions.  This might be helpful(http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.r-bloggers.com%2Flinear-regression-with-correlated-data%2F&ei=trzNVNOrEc_GsQTA2IG4Dw&usg=AFQjCNGFwUG4p6IGFDhk1t5x8ttj0rOoMA&sig2=O8djBvvzGkmD30kBgvU0DQ&bvm=bv.85076809,d.cWc)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It gives me more reasonable answers than I was getting with acf(), where "reasonable" is defined as closer to what was obtained before.